# Scrolling down a page with embed pdf makes the background and the pdf frame disappear

Tags: wordpress, pdf

I'm using PDFjs Viewer (plugin) to embed pdf documents into posts and pages. This is the plugin that best fits to my needs and more over it is not based on Google doc embedder, which reduces the quality of the documents and at some point runs out of quota or whatever message it was showing.

So I have this problem, when scrolling down a page with embeded documents the background flashes white and the pdf frame disappear. It happens only under Chrome. Here is the website http://olimp-online.com/. Just open any post.

Many thanks!

Comment: I don't see any problem in Chrome v37.0.2062.120 m. Try disabling all your Chrome extensions. It could be coming from a conflict with one of these.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Tried that but still the problem persist.